# dimension of singular locus and complete intersection of a hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a reduced projective hypersurface over a field $k$, which is defined by the homogeneous equation $f(T_0,\ldots,T_n)=0$. If the dimension of the singular locus of $X$ is $s$, $0\leq s\leq n-2$. For $\alpha=(a_0,\ldots,a_n)\in k^{n+1}$, we define
$$\partial _\alpha f=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_i}.$$
Can we always find $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-s-1}\in k^{n+1}$, such that 
$$V(f)\cap V(\partial_{\alpha_1}f)\cap\cdots\cap V(\partial_{\alpha_{n-s-1}} f)$$
is a complete intersection? Here $V(f)$ means the projective hypersurface defined by the homogeneous equation $f=0$.

I think the hard part of this problem is when $k$ is a finite field.

If you can solve the case when $k$ is infinite, that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il faut de supposer que $k$ est un corps assez grand.

D'abord, on supposer que $k'$ est une cl\^oture alg\'ebrique du corps $k$, alors $k'$ est infini. Si on a l'assertion pour un tel $k'$, il existe une extension finie du corps $k$ qui satisfait le besoin aussi.

D'apr`es le crit`ere jacobien, on a
$$\dim\left(V(f)\cap V(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_0})\cap \cdots\cap V(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_n})\right)=\dim X^{sing}=s.$$

On raisonne par r\'ecurrence sur le nombre de combinations $k'$-lin\'eairs dans l'intersection. Soit
$$
  V_{t}=V(f)\cap V(\partial_{\alpha_1}f)\cap\cdots\cap V(\partial_{\alpha_t}f)
$$
Le cas de $t=0$ est \'evident. Si on a d\'ej`a trouv\'e $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_t\in k'^{n+1}$, tels que $V_t$ est une intersection compl`ete, o`u $1\leqslant t\leqslant n-s$. Soient $U_1,\ldots,U_h$ toutes les composantes irr\'eductibles de $V_{t}$ d\'efini au-dessus.

Si pour tout $\beta\in k'^{n+1}$, il toujours existe une $U_i$, telle que $U_i\subseteq V_t$, alors on a
$$U_i\subseteq V_t\subset V(f)\cap V(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_0})\cap \cdots\cap V(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_n}),$$
qui contredit avec ce que $\dim X^{sing}=s<n-t-1$.

Si on peut trouver une famille de $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k\in k'^{n+1}$, tels que
[U_i\nsubseteq V(\partial_{\beta_i}f)]
pour tout $i=1,\ldots,h$. On d\'efinit
$$L(U_i)=\{\alpha=(a_0,\ldots,a_{n+1})\in k'^{n+1}|U_i\subseteq V(\partial _{\alpha}f)\}.$$
Alors dans ce cas, pour tout $i=1,\ldots,h$, $L(U_i)$ est un sous-espace vectoriel propre de $k'^{n+1}$. Comme $k'$ est infini, il toujours existe un vecteur $\beta=(b_0,\ldots,b_{n+1})\in k'^{n+1}\smallsetminus\{0\}$, tel que
$$\beta\not\in\bigcup_{i=1}^n L(U_i).$$
Alors $U_1,\ldots,U_h\nsubseteq V(\partial_{\beta}f)$, donc $V(\partial_{\beta}f)\cap V_t$ est une intersection compl`ete.

Donc on peut trouver $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-s-1}$, qui satisfont le besoin, et c'est la fin de la d\'emonstration.